# why the donor card disppear and the form become empty when I change the route in React js using Redux

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

`I hope you are doing well, I have an issue I am building a donation web app, and I am using React and Redux, so that when I the user add his info in the form like phone number and blood type after adding and if he moves to another route the form becomes empty and the donor card disappear.

is that any solution to keep the donor card and form still filled and disabled in the component even though the user change the route?

any help Is appreciated

[view the problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd6sg.gif)

[Add component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mTjBQ.jpg) 
[Donor Card component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wyT4h.png)

Answer (score 1):

> after a couple of hours, I have just solved the issue by using localStorage, data persisting is the key

`localstorage` is not a good approach to solve this issue. localstorage is for keeping the data after reload, but in here you want to keep the data after the route changes. (Note that `react-dom-router` doesn't reload the page.)

the problem is that while you configured redux in your code, you're using `useReducer` for user inputs state:

```
const [userInput, setUserInput] = React.useReducer(
  (state, newState) => ({...state, ...newState}),
  {
    bloodType: "",
    phoneNumber: "",
  }
)
```

`useReducer` is local reducer for react, and it doesn't use `redux`. so your input state is local and it'll get loosed after chaging the route. (while redux store is global and is shared between components.)

Since your component is using `redux` already, You can instead add a reducer for `Input` in redux, and then map that to the component props in `mapstatetoprops` function, so that you can access it with `this.props.userInput`. this way you don't loose the state after the route changes, since redux store provider is global.

Answer (score 0):

Redux helps to achive that. My suggestion is to use `useEffect()` on the component and ask to the redux store if there is any value stored. If it is then you need to fill the fields/values with those values.
Is it clear?
You can post your code, will help a lot to help you with more details.

Answer (score 0):

after a couple of hours, I have just solved the issue by using **localStorage**, data persisting  is the key